# Fire OnclientClick after Onclick for asp.net button control

Tags: asp.net, button, onclick, onclientclick

Is it possible to fire the onclientclick after the onclick event for asp.net button?
I am sending some values in session from onclick event and then I want to fire onclientclick.
Any help would be advisable.

Comment: I believe that can not be happen. But you can use ajax. On client click go to server and write things to session.

Comment: I mean that can not be happen as you said it, without a trick.

Comment: It's highly *unlikely* that this is possible due to the `OnClick` being a postback that results in a new page, and the `OnClientClick` being a client side script function. Clearly the script of this page will happen before the result of the postback provides the new page, otherwise the script is no longer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the javascript function using register client script inside the onclick of the button.

```
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType, "Javascript", 
"YourButton_OnClientClick_Handler();", true);
```

Comment: I am using the same but this is not opening the page in new tab(as my client side script opens a new tab), when I am calling same function from server side.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an Update Panel? If yes, capture the endrequest and write code there..

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequest);
```